# How to capture video from a PS Vita?

Tags: ps-vita, streaming

I've been exploring the idea of streaming from a PS Vita which should be a lot easier than it has been.  I currently use a stationary camera mounted over a desk to do so. I have read about a service to add an HDMI port but I cannot find anyone who has used this service and has had success with the results to justify the cost.

Comment: If your computer is good enough, you can emulate the console instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time I hear about a HDMI mod, but there is one that lets you get the video through a mini USB 2.0 port, though it's not the cheapest thing to get. Costs roughly $200'ish just for the mod itself. That's not counting the Vita.

Quality seems to be alright I guess. Don't think we're allowed to link to the site directly, but if you google for "ps vita capture card" you're bound to find the thing I'm talking about.

Comment: Why shouldn't you be allowed to link it? Is it an illegal product?

Answer (score 0):

On PS Vita consoles with Homebrew, you can install a Plugin called [UDCD UVC](https://github.com/xerpi/vita-udcd-uvc) to make your Vita console act as a camera via USB. This can be used to capture the screen of the console with apps like the Windows Camera and OBS Studio.

The only downside of this is that it only transfers video, meaning that you will need to run a 3.5mm TRS cable from the audio output of the Vita to the Line Input of your PC (usually a Blue connector on the back).

Here is an example of a 2nd gen Vita being captured by the Windows Camera app:

[image]